# how to show all look up value with associated null value?

Tags: sql, database

Question:

Let's say I have condition code A,B,C in a lookup table

I got a query result say

```
Maker  Condition InspectionYear Count  
Toyota      A    2009           1
```

How should I write Sql to show this result instead?

```
Maker  Condition InspectionYear Count  
Toyota      A    2009           1
Toyota      B    2009           0
Toyota      C    2009           0
```

Comment: You need a LEFT JOIN. What table contains values B and C?

Comment: what are the records currently in your table?

Comment: Can you please mention your query also ?

Comment: what are the tables involved with this?

Comment: So bad of me, why I quickly think of FizzBuzz with the way the OP described his problem. To the OP, please put some effort on explaining the problem requirement, e.g. the input and expected output

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are filtering the result according to 'Count' field. If I'm not misunderstanding, why don't you just remove count restriction?

Comment: Only got the one record result from others.  I figured it out actually. Using Cross Join  and then outer join the result. Thanks!